# (Python, Numpy: type hinting), How to correctly convert "integer" value to "_DType@clip"?

Tags: python, numpy, casting, type-hinting, pyright

I'm having trouble with `Numpy (version 1.25)` Type hinting.
Suppose following code (`/tmp/asdf.py`):

```python
import numpy as np

tx: int = 32 
out_tx = np.clip(
        tx,
        0, 
        100,
        )
```

`pyright` is giving me following errors:

```sh
$ pyright /tmp/asdf.py
/tmp/asdf.py
  /tmp/asdf.py:5:9 - error: Argument of type "Literal[32]" cannot be assigned to parameter "a" of type "ndarray[_DType@clip]" in function "clip"
    "Literal[32]" is incompatible with "ndarray[_DType@clip]" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
  /tmp/asdf.py:6:9 - error: Argument of type "Literal[0]" cannot be assigned to parameter "a_min" of type "_DType@clip" in function "clip"
    Type "Literal[0]" is incompatible with constrained type variable "_DType" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
  /tmp/asdf.py:7:9 - error: Argument of type "Literal[100]" cannot be assigned to parameter "a_max" of type "_DType@clip" in function "clip"
    Type "Literal[100]" is incompatible with constrained type variable "_DType" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
3 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations
```

- How to correctly convert in Literal `"integer"` into `Numpy's "_DType@clip"`, such that `pyright` won't output this messages?

---

Update:

- I forgot to mention that I'm on `numpy v1.25`.
- On `numpy v.1.24`, `pyright` doesn't output any warning
- I know that above code works.
- I was just looking for the safest way to write, because I really like static-analyzers/linters/LSPs.

Comment: There is no need to convert anything. Your code is correct. The types match [one of the overloaded signatures](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.25.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyi#L398). This must be a bug with Pyright. Mypy has no issue with this code either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why `pyright` was outputting error when it shouldn't have output an error:

The reason was that I also installed `data-science-types` package.
And it seems it has override `numpy`'s typing.

After uninstalling it (with `pip3 uninstall data-science-types`) `pyright` doesn't output this error again.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer 1

Pyright should not return errors, first try to reinstall pyright and numpy with `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyright numpy`.

If it didn't work, as explained in the [pyright documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/type-stubs.md#importance-of-type-stub-files) :

> Regardless of the search path, Pyright always attempts to resolve an import with a type stub (“.pyi”) file before falling back to a python source (“.py”) file.

And Numpy has these .pyi files, for the clip function with integers as parameters we have https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyi#L397-L408 :

```
@overload
def clip(
    a: _ScalarLike_co,
    a_min: None | ArrayLike,
    a_max: None | ArrayLike,
    out: None = ...,
    *,
    dtype: None = ...,
    where: None | _ArrayLikeBool_co = ...,
    order: _OrderKACF = ...,
    subok: bool = ...,
    signature: str | tuple[None | str, ...] = ...,
) -> Any: ...
```

And with this there should be no errors for your case.

So it looks like your pyright takes into account some stub files (otherwise the requested type will be Any, not "_DType@clip"), but not those from Numpy. You can try to find it with options which are something like "go to definition" for the most well-known IDEs.

## Answer 2

You can use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) but that would mean lying to pyright to match the signature of the `clip` function which is already bad

```
import typing
import numpy as np

tx: int = 32
out_tx = np.clip(
        typing.cast(np.ndarray, tx),
        typing.cast(np.ndarray, 0),
        typing.cast(np.ndarray, 1),
        )
```

or instead of `np.ndarray`, every type that does not return warnings

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, following fixes the last 2 warnings:

```python
import numpy as np

tx: int = 32
out_tx = np.clip(
    np.int32(tx),    # still expects array, produces warning
    np.int32(0),     # this fixed
    np.int32(100),   # this fixed
)
```